# How to change the port-number of a PostGIS layer's data source outside QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, data-source

I have several QGIS project files (qgz) I didn't touch in quite some time that contain several layers heavily depending on a PostGIS connection and meanwhile its port number was changed (everything else of the connection is unchanged). Now I am aware of the changeDataSource plugin and back in the days I used to textedit qgs files for that purpose

My problem is that QGIS crashes when I open said project file after I have to cancel all the db-credential prompts. So I wonder which way is more promising:

- Change the port number via editor in qgs and wrap it somehow in its qgz?
- Provide the desired port number to QGIS via proxy or SSH tunnel if that's even possible?

Comment: take a copy of your qgz and rename it .zip >extract the file and you can edit the .qgs file with the port changes needed.

Comment: You could also write a Python function to do these steps in-memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the commenters I did it the zip way.

In case of using Windows I recommend a using 7-zip because it automatically recognizes zip-based file formats and provides the context menus on right-click accordingly. Surely, writing a python script for that is doable but not justifiable at the moment.